# Asana Connect (OAuth) - Issue when logging in via Google

Tags: asana

When logging in via Google (through Asana Connect from iOS App) the following error gets presented in the browser window: 'invalid_request: The required parameter 'redirect_uri' is missing.'

Logging in via username and password works absolutely fine.

Is that an issue at my end or within the Asana Connect API ?

Any idea how to fix this issue ?

A very interesting thing though ... when going back to the app and logging in again, the authentication happens successfully without asking for user credentials, returning to the app with valid accessToken & refreshToken.

Comment: When sending an email to asana's API support it says "Please post your question / problem on Stackoverflow. We monitore it regularly.". 4 weeks later ... no response from asana here on Stackoverflow. What is then the correct channel to get API issues sorted?

Comment: I have this same issue, have you figured out if it's you or asana yet? I suspect it's asana because the callback from the google does not include the redirect-uri.

Comment: I'm programming for mobile, so I was able to intercept that request and append the redirect_uri and response_type but if you're developing a web-app I dont think you have that option. I have emailed support at api-support@asana.com I'll update this question when I hear back. I've also linked this page in case they want to answer directly.

Comment: It appears this is only an issue with the mobile OAuth via Google. I have updated the issue ticket but have only heard back from a representative, no developers yet.

Comment: We're currently looking into this - is it correct that this is only an issue on mobile?

Comment: @agnoster Yes.This happens only with mobile.It works fine on webpages.This issue still remains.When I Kill the app and open again.It works fine.is there a way to fix this issue??

Answer (score 0):

I too use `GTMOAuth` for mac. This error occurs because in a normal web browser when we click login with google account, a new browser window opens to get credentials. using `GTMOAuth` it embeds only a single webview and so its unable to present a new browser window for google credentials to be used.